# How to list tables (by prefix) with Azure.Data.Tables?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I use `Azure.Data.Tables`.
I found that most likely I should use `Azure.Data.Tables.TableServiceClient.QueryAsync(...)` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableserviceclient.queryasync?view=azure-dotnet#azure-data-tables-tableserviceclient-queryasync(system-string-system-nullable((system-int32))-system-threading-cancellationtoken))) to list tables, however I cannot find any documentation on the syntax of the filter string. I could avoid specifying a filter string and do the filtering on client side but it's not a proper way to do it.

There is only one example in the docs:

```
filter
String
Returns only tables that satisfy the specified filter. For example, the following would filter tables with a Name of 'foo': "TableName eq 'foo'".
```

But where is the full documentation for the filter string, and more specifically, how can I list tables by prefix? In `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.CloudTableClient.ListTables` it seems it can be done easily ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.cloudtableclient.listtables?view=azure-dotnet)) but microsoft [recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/653401/what-is-the-difference-between-azuredatatables-vs.html) moving to `Azure.Data.Tables`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of version 12.4.0 of Azure.Data.Tables SDK, it is not possible.

However I did find an issue on SDK repository on GitHub: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/24414 which pointed me to a workaround here: https://github.com/NuGet/Insights/blob/6d23681b17d7c131f7f2ab25b111fc4bcb421ba6/src/ExplorePackages.Logic/Storage/TableExtensions.cs.

From the 2nd link:

```
public static AsyncPageable<TableItem> GetTablesAsync(this TableServiceClient client, string prefix)
{
    var prefixQuery = TableClient.CreateQueryFilter<TableItem>(
        x => x.TableName.CompareTo(prefix) >= 0
          && x.TableName.CompareTo(prefix + char.MaxValue) <= 0);

    return client.GetTablesAsync(filter: prefixQuery);
}
```

Comment: This could work. Instead of `TableClient.CreateQueryFilter<TableItem>(` I'd use `TableServiceClient.CreateQueryFilter(`. Do you know where I could find full documentation on how to specify the filter?

Comment: I was not able to find the documentation unfortunately. I ended up looking at the code on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Seems method `listTables()` has been added to `TableServiceClient` :

```
PagedIterable<TableItem> tableItems = tableServiceClient.listTables();
tableItems.forEach(tableItem -> System.out.printf("Retrieved table with name '%s'.%n", tableItem.getName()));
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.data.tables.tableserviceclient?view=azure-java-stable#com-azure-data-tables-tableserviceclient-listtables()

Comment: Dude - the question is for C# and yet you point to a method for Java...

Answer (score 1):

Here's working method tested in **Azure.Data.Tables SDK** **12.8.1**

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the names of all the tables in azure storage
        /// </summary>
        public static List<string> GetAllTableNames()
        {
            string connectionString = Secrets.API_STORAGE; // Replace with your storage account's connection string
            var serviceClient = new TableServiceClient(connectionString);
            var tableResponses =  serviceClient.Query();
            var tableNames = new List<string>();
            foreach (var table in tableResponses)
            {
                tableNames.Add(table.Name);
            }
            return tableNames;
        }
```